# Comparison between actual and expected assertions result in soapui

Tags: soapui

I created a soap test step and added assertions to it but want to display the actual result in assertions and expected result is that possible?

Comment: Can you share your actual code? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but default `assert` behavior is to show the actual and expected result.

Comment: Missing token [<StatusDesc>Success.</StatusDesc>
] in Response;
[StatusCode] Missing token [200] in Response;

Comment: Sorry I don't get you. This is your actual message? What do you message want instead?

Comment: @MarwaAbdelgawad, do you want to show sample response and what you wanted to assert?

Comment: @ i want to show the actual value returned in soapui response align with the assertion expected value is it possible?

Comment: Still having this trouble? is it possible to some sample response and what you want to compare? a screen shot or data would help.